# ClassNotFoundException for class in context.xml while jar is in lib folder of catalina home

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, redis, wicket

I am following [this tuturial](https://github.com/baholladay/WicketRedisSession) to make my current wicket project work with Redis Session management.
However, I can't make my context.xml work.
I am making a JAR from 2 files, CatalinaRedisSessionStore and RedisCache, then I am putting that jar in the lib folder of tomcat.

After starting my application I am getting this error:

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement Begin event threw exception
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore
```

My context.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Context>
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
             maxIdleBackup="1"
             minIdleSwap="0"
             maxIdleSwap="0"
             processExpiresFrequency="1"
             saveOnRestart='true'>
        <Store className="com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore"/>
    </Manager>
</Context>
```

I am running my application in a docker container, using `azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11`

When I inspect my docker container, the jar file is in the lib folder of the tomcat home, so according to the docs that should be sufficient for tomcat to find the class. Below I have put my Dockerfile.

Does anyone have any clue why the class cannot be found?

Dockerfile

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11


RUN apk update && apk add bash

#set timezone to "Europe/Amsterdam"
RUN apk add tzdata && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime && echo "Europe/Amsterdam" >  /etc/timezone && apk del tzdata

COPY /build/distributions/Application*.zip /opt/application/

RUN unzip /opt/application/Application*zip -d /opt/application && rm /opt/application/Application*.zip && chmod 775 /opt/application/apache-tomcat/bin/catalina.sh && chmod 775 /opt/application/apache-tomcat/bin/docker-healthcheck.sh

WORKDIR /opt/application/apache-tomcat

EXPOSE 8080 9875 9000

# Define default command.
CMD ["/opt/application/apache-tomcat/bin/dockerstart.sh","arg1"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=10s --retries=3 --start-period=2m CMD /opt/application/apache-tomcat/bin/docker-healthcheck.sh
```

After executing jar xf redis_session.jar, folder structure as follows:
[image: jar file structure]

Comment: what is "<path>" doing there?

Comment: It's the path where the file is. It contains the name of the product, which I cannot give here on the forum. Will update it to prevent confusion

Comment: `<path>.` is definitely wrong, and nor `<` nor `>` are valid characters for "package identifiers". ..assuming you compiled the original sample, try `className="CatalinaRedisSessionStore"`

Comment: Adjusted that just now

Comment: ok, ..i also though is the exact error message :)

Comment: ..but ClassNotFound is quite speaking! (ensure that class in that jar in that lib folder)

Comment: I actually did put the jar file in the correct place so the class should be found. It's in the title of my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221097/discussion-between-peter-van-leeuwen-and-xerx593).

Comment: @PetervanLeeuwen Please, can you provide more details about your Dockerfile? How are you deploying Wicket inside it? On the other hand, and please, forgive me if it may seem too obvious, but have you checked that the classes are indeed in the right package in the indicated jars?

Comment: How is the jar file getting there? Maybe it is copied into the lib folder *after* the tomcat has started? That would explain it.

Comment: @jccampanero Wicket is part of my spring application. Before we used docker, we just deployed it in a normal tomcat installation. The application is starting fine when I am removing my context.xml, so that shouldn't be the issue I think. 

After I started the application, I checked the jars in my docker container, and the jar is in the lib folder.

Comment: @cheffe Before the tomcat is deployed, I am creating a zip file, with gradle, which is used to deploy the docker container. In that zip file, the folder structure is already defined and the redis_session.jar is in the lib folder. 
When using lsof, I can also see the file is used. Not sure if that helps

Comment: Thank you Peter. If I understand correctly, you have a zip file, which contains tomcat and all required libraries, including your application and the jars which should be placed in the ```lib``` folder. Then, you copy this zip file into the container and uncompress it. And your ```ENTRYPOINT``` starts tomcat. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed question. Yes the tomcat is in the zip file, in the zip file there is a folder called apache-tomcat, which contains a lib folder, which contains the jars. I don't have an ENTRYPOINT in my Dockerfile. I will edit my question and add the docker file in my question

Comment: Given that everything seems ok, I suspect the issue is something that you are given for granted not be as you expect, like, what error do you have if you do `java -cp your-customjar.jar com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore`? (you should have some errors saying that it is missing a main method, if not the jar is not correct)

Comment: @rascio Indeed I am getting the following error: Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. The Dockerfile looks fine... Related to your last comment, and as I said you when I asked you for forgiveness if it seems to obvious in a previous comment, are you sure that your ```redis_session.jar``` contents are appropriate? I mean, does it include the two classes? Are the two classes defined in the right packages and corresponding folder structure?

Comment: Yep, that error means that java is not able to find that class in the jar, so Tomcat is fine, the issue reside in the content of that jar, how are you building it?

Comment: I am building the jar as follows:
1. I am going to the java folder
2. Entering the following command: jar cvf redis_session.jar com/company/web/wicket/redis/CatalinaRedisSessionStore.java com/company/web/wicket/redis/RedisCache.java
3. Then when I unpack the jar, doing the following command:  jar xf redis_session.jar
4. I have added the folder structure in my question

Comment: Peter, you must compress the ```class``` files, not the ```java``` files. It can be the problem. Please, can you verify that the jar contains the ```class``` files?

Comment: @jccampanero Indeed I did that wrong it seems. I have now compiled the generated class files. (changed the screenshot in the question also). However, the error is still there: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.web.wicket.redis.CatalinaRedisSessionStore

(a few lines later):

SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Occurred at line [9] column [84]

Comment: Nice Peter! Please, to try to reproduce the issue, what version of tomcat are you using? Is it a standard installation? Please, can you describe the contents of the dockerstart.sh script? Please, excuse me, I do not think so, but I cannot remember if it is a standard tomcat file

Comment: @jccampanero It would be the greatest if we can have a call. Would that be possible for you? I would be really thankful if you can make some time for that.

Comment: Peter, I am so sorry, I will try to help you in any way I can, but I prefer not to contact anyone in private. Hope you understand. If you want, we can start a chat to make the conversation more dynamic and try to solve the problem more quickly.

Comment: I think Kenan has already given you the correct answer. I'm sorry I wasn't more helpful Peter.

Comment: @jccampanero He indeed gave the right answer. It's working. Nevertheless thanks a lot for your time and detailed answers!

Comment: You are welcome @PetervanLeeuwen. I am glad to hear that you could solve your problem. I hope to see you again.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the Application*.zip file you copy into the Docker image contains the Tomcat installation.

Changing your Dockerfile as follows should solve the problem:

```sh
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11

RUN apk update && apk add bash

#set timezone to "Europe/Amsterdam"
RUN apk add tzdata && \
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime && \
    echo "Europe/Amsterdam" >  /etc/timezone && \
    apk del tzdata

COPY /build/distributions/Application*.zip /tmp/

# Setting CATALINA_HOME and updating the PATH env vars is crucial
# since you use an inofficial Tomcat base image
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

# The default path of Tomcat is /usr/local/tomcat
# So, it's a good idea to extract your application to that folder
# rather than to a custom one to avoid an unexpected behaviour of the Tomcat
RUN unzip  /tmp/Application*.zip -d /usr/local && \
    rm /tmp/Application*.zip && \
    mv /usr/local/apache-tomcat ${CATALINA_HOME} && \
    chmod 775 ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina.sh && \
    chmod 775 ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/dockerstart.sh && \
    chmod 775 ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/docker-healthcheck.sh

WORKDIR ${CATALINA_HOME}

EXPOSE 8080 9875 9000

# Define default command.
# Everything inside /usr/local/tomcat/bin is exposed through the $PATH env var we defined at the beginning. 
# So we can access them globally without having to specify the exact script path
CMD ["dockerstart.sh", "run"]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=1m --timeout=10s --retries=3 --start-period=2m CMD ${CATALINA_HOME}/bin/docker-healthcheck.sh
```